# Where is the generated token stored when a user logs in and how to use it to authenticate that user for further requests?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, jwt

This is my first time trying to create a Web API in Visual Studio using C#.I'm using a database which has a table User. When I want to make request such as logging in and seeing more information I want to authenticate the user. The login method seems to be working just fine, it checks the user's credentials, validates them in the database, lets the user login if the credentials are right and generates the jwt bearer token. I'm generating the token based on claims. However, I don't know how to limit any of the GET, POST, PUT methods for authorized users based on the token. I'm confused as to how will the program know whether you are logged in and can make other requests or not? Should I create another field in the User model which will store let's say true or false for authorization(the token)? And how do I test it using swagger or postman?

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt: Issuer"],
                        ValidAudience = Configuration["Hwt: Audience"],
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
                    };
                });
```

Comment: Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-6.0. Policies should be the way to go to limit access to api endpoints based on claims.

Comment: It would help if you showed how you generate that "token". Is it a JWT Bearer token?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this can get you pointed in the right direction, you need to wire up a few things for this. You will need to tweak this answer to whatever token scheme you are using, but hopefully this gets you started and you can google from here.

In the startup.cs file add something like this

```
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, policy =>
                {
                    policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                    policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Name);
                });
            });
```

In startup.cs where you are setting your IApplicationBuilder app:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Then in each controller you can decorate the top of the controller with these attributes.

```
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "BasicAuthentication")]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class CustomerController : ControllerBase
```

You don't need all 3 of these, tailor this to whatever token scheme you are using.

You can also decorate the individual endpoints with these attributes, when doing it at the top of the controller class it applies them to all the endpoints.

Comment: Could you re-check the code in my startup class? I added it in the post. I cannot add options.AddPolicy, only seperately and even then it doesn't work.

Comment: @StarLink111 What version of .net are you using? It has changed slightly between versions. Add that to your question too